# Increasing size of mounting holes on LCD

Tags: lcd, mount

I've had a cheapish LCD for a while now which I use on various electronics projects. I'm looking to mount it for a project and the holes on the board are very small, smaller than any screws I have available anyway!

Here are the pics:

[image: lcd front]
[image: lcd back]

So in each corner there is a mounting hole. Could anyone let me know if it's a wise or not so wise idea to try and increase the size of these holes? By using a drill of some sort. The size I need isn't far from this but at the moment they are too small. Thanks

Comment: Get smaller screws.  Why are we even here talking about this?

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a problem, as the pads round the holes are quite large and well clear of any tracks, and it will be a conventional two-layer board. You should be able to find suitable screws, though; the holes are usually 2.5 mm diameter.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my earlier post I guess, but the problem is the diameter of the mounting holes on the board is  2mm (i.d say  but not quite 2.5mm so any suitable screws I can find are either too large and would cut into the board or they are lose enough but not are not long enough. Ideally I would like to use motherboard mounting screws but they are about 3mm and would cut in.

Answer (score 1):

- Drilling the holes slightly larger has a high chance of success if you are sensibly careful
  **BUT**  makes very little sense.
- The question suggests that you are "cost sensitive" and that the panel is valuable to you and that this is a one off requirement. There is of course no problem with any of those aspects. However ...
- Unless your circumstances are very exceptional it should be trivially easy to obtain 4 screws with nuts that meet your need.

  Most surplus and completely dead and valueless items of surplus electronic  equipment are liable to contain suitable screws.

  Things like printers, CD or DVD drives, "stereos" / sound systems and more which are discarded in large quantity in the UK are likely to contain suitable screws.

  New screws that are suitable should be available from some or other UK source at a few tens of pence at most, and for pence in likelihood. (People will charge you 1 GBP for 4 screws with nuts and washers if you let them. Don't let them ).
- **Drilling  would probably work. BUT ... :** There is about a 95% chance that you can enlarge these holes to 3mm or 1/8th inch without any problem if you are sensibly careful.

  If they are already that large then it would be so easy to obtain screws as above, that drilling makes vanishingly little sense.

  Drilling well inside the copper of the existing pads - say NOT MORE than 3mm or 1/8 th inch total diameter, is **unlikely** to cut a track or short layers in a mutilayer PCB.

  **BUT it may.**

  There is also the chance if you are not 100% careful and/or if you are unlucky that the drill will bind and damage the board in an unexpected way.

  While this is unlikely it is hard to see, in your circumstances, that the risk is worthwhile compared to finding 4 screws.

Comment: I'm not necessarily cost-sensitive, but I have been to a few retailers looking for screws small and long enough for the job and they are tricky to come by. As I commented in the other answer the diameter is 2mm and so anything I've come across as close to suitable are not quite right. I would like to use mobo mounting screws but these would definitely cut into the board. I don't really want to drill, but not sure what would be better - drilling or cutting with the screws.

Comment: In terms of risk, I have another LCD I think I will have to use for this project. I just wasn't sure of the risks of doing this so thanks I guess ;)

Comment: You can avoid the risks of violent damage to the board by using a pen drill that is turned with your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with drilling the holes larger. Simply select the drill you need and make sure the device is clamped in a vice or something before you drill. Make sure that you use a high speed for drilling, otherwise the drill bit may bite and wreck the PCB. Push with a light pressure and feed slowly, be extra careful at the end when the bit breaks through as theres a chance that it will catch and suddenly pull forward.

Usually they use carbide bits to drill PCBs because the glass in it is super abrasive against high speed steel (normal drill bits). In your case, it won't really matter as your not drilling very many holes.

As for screws, that modal is pretty common, I've found that #4-40 machine screws work just fine with them for mounting.

But yea...this has little to do with electronics...

Comment: +1 for the biting bit (pun intended). I would actually prefer to use HSS bits for enlarging holes, epecially for smaller holes (2mm probably not too bad) IME, Tungsten Carbide catch and snap easily when used on an existing hole. The HSS are more flexible (and don't cut as well) so they actually work better for this. Of course for drilling fresh holes TC is the type to use for FR4, otherwise you are swapping bits every 5 holes :-)